# How to discover host in a network considering all kinds of IP?

Tags: android, networking

I'm developing an Android application, I have to implement a function that discover all the host of the network where I'm connected (for example WiFi).

I implemented a function that work, this is my code:

```
public class ScanNetwork {

    private static final int NB_THREADS = 10;
    private ArrayList < String > hosts;

    public ArrayList < String > ScanNetwork(String ipAddress) {

        hosts = new ArrayList <> ();
        String subnet = ipAddress.substring(0, ipAddress.lastIndexOf("."));

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);
        for (int dest = 0; dest < 255; dest++) {
            String host = subnet + "." + dest;
            executor.execute(pingRunnable(host));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

        return hosts;
    }

    private Runnable pingRunnable(final String host) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                    boolean reachable = inet.isReachable(1000);

                    if (reachable) {
                        hosts.add(host);
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.out.println("Log: " + e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Log: " + e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This code work on a certain category of IP such as 192.168.1.10, but not for each other like 10.1.25.1.

The question in simple, how I can implement a function that discover all host in a certain network considering all kinds of IP?

Comment: What do you mean by "category of IP"?  192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x are both RFC 1918 private addresses.  Also, x.x.x.1 through x.x.x.255 isn't the entire network, you need to take the subnet mask into account.

Comment: There is actually no foolproof way to do this. You seem to be trying to do this in IPv4, and you could end up with something like a `/8` network, with about 24 million possible addresses. With the other kind of IP, IPv6, you will usually have enough possible addresses that it will take over half a million years at 1 million addresses checked per second.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Sorry for my bad explanation, I mean: I need to discover all host in a network, suppose a  Wi-Fi net. So with my code I get the current IP, and I scan a range of IP. This code it work always?

Comment: There are multiple reasons you may not be able to discover all the hosts on a LAN. For instance, there may be hosts which are set to not respond to ICMP (ping), or you may be on a Private VLAN, where hosts on the same VLAN simply cannot communicate with other hosts on the same VLAN. There are lots of tools which use various methods, and some use many methods, to try to do this, but there is no foolproof way to do it. It is simply not part of IP or LAN protocols to do this.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, I know different tools  that do what I want, like "Fing", but the problem is that for a job I need to implement in a Android app a function that work as I descrive before. I tried to implement the code posted but is not complete. There are some java library or a github project that Can help me? I search in stack , Google ecc but i don't discover anything

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. Whatever you get to do this may miss hosts; you just can't guarantee you will find them all.